# Empty functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jslint

If I have something like this:

```
var blah = function() { };
```

and then later in code blah is being used, what is the JSLint hint that says remove the empty block?

Comment: Probably because that function block (`{ }`) does nothing.

Comment: I dunno...I could think of situations where it makes sense. `myClass.overridableFunction = function() { };` wouldn't throw an error if you call `overridableFunction()`, and then an extension of the class could implement it further.

Comment: That or a `noop` function. It happens.

Comment: if you use jQuery you can do `var blah = $.noop;`

Comment: in addition to jQuery, `noop` functions are found in many libs & frameworks, such as lodash and angular.

Comment: I am also writing something like this for a closure to initialise, is it not a good way to initialise with empty fn.. !

Answer (score 38):

I don't know what `jsLint` thinks but if this is a problem and you need a solution then you can do something like the following:

```
var blah = function() { return undefined; }; // or just return;
```

**Update :** I think, `Bergi`'s guess is right because, on the [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) site in the `Required Blocks` section :

> JSLint expects that if, while, do and for statements will be made with
>   blocks {that is, with statements enclosed in braces}.JavaScript allows
>   an if to be written like this:if (condition) statement;That form is
>   known to contribute to mistakes in projects where many programmers are
>   working on the same code. That is why JSLint expects the use of a
>   block:

```
if (condition) { statements; }
```

> Experience shows that this form is more resilient.

So, It probably just checks for empty blocks `{ }` and invalidate the blank function.

Comment: @Ian, Yep, it's undefined at all.

Comment: If you are using jQuery then you could also call $.noop() instead of a return;

Answer (score 30):

Use the lambda expression:

```
const blah = () => void 0;
```

This will make it clear that `blah` is an empty function that returns `undefined`.

Comment: This is the absolutely correct answer!

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking what JsLint option turns this warning off it is: "debug:true"

Strangely, the docs make no reference to this behavior:

> "Tolerate debugger statements" | *debug* | *true* if *debugger* statements should be allowed. Set this option to *false* before going into production.

But if you look at [the code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js), you can see that it won't warn you with the debug option set to true:

```
function block(kind) {
    // A block is a sequence of statements wrapped in braces.

    ...

    if (kind !== 'catch' && array.length === 0 && !option.debug) {
        curly.warn('empty_block');
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A lot of code checkers check for this sort of thing.  It doesn't mean you should *never* have empty code blocks.  Sometimes there are valid reasons for having them.  But it *often* means that the programmer just forgot to write the implementation. :)

What I like to do is put a comment in the function body, explaining why it's empty.  This should suppress the warning, but it may not depending on whether the code checker considers a code block with a comment "empty".

```
var blah = function() { /* empty because ... */ };
```

Comment: A good convention, though jshint will still complain, because Crocker.

Comment: This is so f** annoying.  Crocker's own code for Object.create uses an empty block and will not pass JSLint.  He needs to figure out who the audience is.  Is it supposed to be used as a pre-production check, or as a sanity check during the development cycle?  Because right now, he is even more confused than normal.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to use the function as a constructor with the `new` operator:

```
// Returns the instance that was just created with the new operator.
var ClassLikeFunction = function(){
    return this; 
};
```

On the other hand, if is intentionally a blank function with no return value:

```
// Returns the same value as a function that returned nothing.
var blankFunction = function(){
    return undefined; 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
{
    ...
}
```

is considered a code block and the hint is letting you know that it is empty (there are no commands in it). You don't have to remove it though, as @Katana314 said, it could be intentional.

Comment: This won't return a `function`, it will only return a `new Object()` (it's a shortcut) and these two a completly different. The only way to return a empty function is to use `var myEmptyMethod = function(){}`. For more information see [Douglas Crockford explanation](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#bonus)

Comment: @RPDeshaies It depends. If evaluated as a statement (i.e. the first `{` is encountered when in statement evaluation mode), then `{ }` will be evaluated as an empty code block. Otherwise, if evaluated as an expression, it will evaluate to a new empty object.

Answer (score 0):

what let me to this question is that I had an empty function in my namespace

and when I called that function, and

```
TypeError: MyNamespcae.myFunction is not a function
```

> so don't create an empty function, at lease add one statement like void(0); or return null;