# ESLint complaining about empty constructor and ngOnInit-implementation

Tags: angular, constructor, eslint

In my Angular application, the rule [*no-empty-function*](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-empty-function.md), triggered an error for my constructor. Well, it **is indeed** an empty body there but the constructor itself needs to be there, because I inject a service.

```
export class ClientListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(service: AuxService) { }
  ngOnInit() { }
  ...
}
```

Interestingly, it also complains about the implemented method for the interface. However, the error messages vary between those two, which perplexes me additionally.

> Unexpected empty constructor.
> Unexpected empty method 'ngOnInit'.

So, it clearly distinguishes between a plain method (be that still required one due to the implemented interface, which itself is wrong in my opinion to nag about) and a constructor. I'm sure that the creators have heard about dependency injection, so I can't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: The linter is correct: your constructor parameter lacks a visibility modifier, so it isn't a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties), so that constructor is indeed empty (and has an unused parameter). If you have an empty method for one of the lifecycle interfaces, i.e. you don't actually do anything on that lifecycle method, you can just... not implement that interface.

Comment: You can remove implements OnInit and ngOnInit method if you are not using those

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to check below link
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty-function

Based on the documentation, below are incorrect

```
    constructor() {}

    foo() {}
```

and these are correct

```
    constructor() {
        // do nothing.
    }

    foo() {
        // do nothing.
    }
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to mention in your answer what the page at the link states. The comment they suggest (as opposed to just an empty body) is to eliminate suspicion/confusion regarding how intentional such an empty body is. I find it too nitty-picky but I get the point.

Comment: Note that's a different rule to `@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function`, which deals just fine without the comment: *"One example of valid TypeScript specific code that would otherwise trigger the `no-empty-function` rule is the use of parameter properties in constructor functions."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't quite understand the comment of yours. Are you saying that the rule I asked about and the rule the replier discusses are different rules? If so, how? If not, what did you mean?

Comment: @KonradViltersten you’re literally linking to different things, yes. The TypeScript ESLint package includes quite a few upgraded versions of core rules to deal with the differences between JS and TS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, your answer is correct and the best fit!

Answer (score 18):

You also could modify your `.eslintrc.json` file to exclude the rule from the linter.

[image]

Comment: thats worked perfectly for me!
for the lazy cats like me I'll just leave the code snippet :
               "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off"

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off" for copy/paste

Answer (score 10):

There is actually a combination of rules, not only one:

```
      "no-empty-function": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
      "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off"
```

I got rid of all the empty-function errors only after I added **the above-given three rules** to the **`.eslintrc.json`** file.

Copy the three rules, paste them in your **`.eslintrc.json`** file (**inside the "rules"**), and you will get rid of the errors.

[image]

Comment: You don't have to turn off the no-empty-function rule. Just turning off, ""@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method" works in Angular 13.

Comment: Thanks, "Kolappan N". It's been quite a long time. I have even forgot where the project is. I'll try it when I found the file.

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit **`.eslintrc.json`** file, and add this line

```
"@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off"
```

Or check out this file

```
{
    "root": true,
    "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts"],
            "parserOptions": {
                "project": ["tsconfig.json"],
                "createDefaultProgram": true
            },
            "extends": [
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
            ],
            "rules": {
                "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
                    "error",
                    {
                        "type": "attribute",
                        "prefix": "app",
                        "style": "camelCase"
                    }
                ],
                "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
                    "error",
                    {
                        "type": "element",
                        "prefix": "app",
                        "style": "kebab-case"
                    }
                ],
                "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off"
            }
        },
        {
            "files": ["*.html"],
            "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
            "rules": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For constructors you can use this settings: `{ "allow": ["functions"] }`. But for `ngOnInit` at this time, there's no solution other than removing the method and `implements OnInit`.